# A number of points on a line, with initial positions and speeds - find a minimum time that any two points meet

Tags: algorithms

How can I compute the minimum time for two points to meet in $O(N)$ time?

All I can think is to compute the time for all the point pairs and get the minimum.

Can anyone give me some hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming we're given an **ordered** list $(y_0,y_1,...,y_{n-1})$ of initial point positions together with a list $(s_0,s_1,...,s_{n-1})$ of their speeds.

You can visualize moving points on a Cartesian plane with "position" and "time" coordinate axes - so the point $P_i$ *trace* will be a ray $R_i$, beginning at the point $(0,y_i)$ and consisting of points $(t, y_i+s_it)$ for $t\ge0$. If points $P_i$ and $P_j$ meet at some time $t$ then their corresponding rays $R_i$ and $R_j$ will intersect, and their intersection point will be $(t,y)$ - we'll call this time $t$ a *meeting time*.

**Observation.** If an intersection point $(t,y)$ for two rays $R_i$ and $R_j$ has a **minimal** meeting time $t$ among all the pairs $(i,j)$ where $i\lt j$, then $i=j-1$ (in other words - points $P_i$ and $P_j$ were initially **neighbor** ones - try to prove that).

So, it means that you can look for minimal meeting time among pairs of neighbor points only - their total number is $O(n)$, and the algorithm time is also linear. If the original list of points is not ordered by their coordinates, then the algorithm time will include sorting, which is $O(n\log(n))$.